# jsonToDOM Function

Tags: javascript, dom

For the MDN documentation website we have written this `jsonToDOM` function and I was wondering how you all would improve it. It takes a json structure and creates DOM elements out of it and appends it to the document. It is written in such a way that the user has to pass the window/document as they might run this code from a scope which has no access to `window` object (Browser addons for example)

```
function jsonToDOM(json, doc, nodes) {

    var namespaces = {
        html: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
        xul: 'http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul'
    };
    var defaultNamespace = namespaces.html;

    function namespace(name) {
        var m = /^(?:(.*):)?(.*)$/.exec(name);        
        return [namespaces[m[1]], m[2]];
    }

    function tag(name, attr) {
        if (Array.isArray(name)) {
            var frag = doc.createDocumentFragment();
            Array.forEach(arguments, function (arg) {
                if (!Array.isArray(arg[0]))
                    frag.appendChild(tag.apply(null, arg));
                else
                    arg.forEach(function (arg) {
                        frag.appendChild(tag.apply(null, arg));
                    });
            });
            return frag;
        }

        var args = Array.slice(arguments, 2);
        var vals = namespace(name);
        var elem = doc.createElementNS(vals[0] || defaultNamespace, vals[1]);

        for (var key in attr) {
            var val = attr[key];
            if (nodes && key == 'key')
                nodes[val] = elem;

            vals = namespace(key);
            if (typeof val == 'function')
                elem.addEventListener(key.replace(/^on/, ''), val, false);
            else
                elem.setAttributeNS(vals[0] || '', vals[1], val);
        }
        args.forEach(function(e) {
            try {
                elem.appendChild(
                                    Object.prototype.toString.call(e) == '[object Array]'
                                    ?
                                        tag.apply(null, e)
                                    :
                                        e instanceof doc.defaultView.Node
                                        ?
                                            e
                                        :
                                            doc.createTextNode(e)
                                );
            } catch (ex) {
                elem.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(ex));
            }
        });
        return elem;
    }
    return tag.apply(null, json);
}
```

[Here's an example of the usage:](http://jsfiddle.net/0mLvafuL/)

```
var json =
['html:div', {style:'background-color:springgreen'},
    ['html:form', {id:'myFirstForm'},
            ['html:input', {type:'text', value:'my field'}],
            ['html:button', {id:'myBtn'}, 'Button Text Content']
    ],
    ['html:form', {id:'mySecondForm'},
            ['html:input', {type:'text', value:'my field for second form'}],
            ['html:div', {},
                'Sub Div with textcontent and siblings',
                ['html:br', {}],
                ['html:input', {type:'checkbox', id:'mycheck'}],
                ['html:label', {for:'mycheck'},
                    'here is text of label, click this text will check the box'
                ]
            ]
    ]
];

document.body.appendChild(jsonToDOM(json, document, {}));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function jsonToDOM(json, doc, nodes)
```

I would suggest better naming for these.

- `json` is a bad name since JSON is a string data transfer format based on JS literal object notation (hence the name). I suggest something like `domTree` (since it's a representation of the DOM) or something.
- `doc` is vague. Why not name it as `document` straight away. If it is `document` then it will just be shadowing the `document` from the outer scope. No harm done.
- `nodes`... Not sure what this does judging by the name. Your example provides a `{}` which isn't very clear what it does. Better name it to something better.

---

```
jsonToDom([
  // very deep tree
], document, {});

// to

jsonToDom(document, {}, [
  // very deep tree
]);
```

I suggest moving `dom` and `nodes` before `json` to allow users to create inlined calls without burying `dom` and `nodes` below the call.

---

```
var namespaces = {
    html: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
    xul: 'http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul'
};

// to

var NAMESPACES= {
    HTML: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
    XUL: 'http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul'
};
```

These appear to be "constants". Use uppercase and underscores convention to indicate constant-ness.

In addition, anything "constant" should be placed in a variable. This includes string literals (like `[object Array]`), patterns (like `/^on/`), and others.

---

```
var defaultNamespace = namespaces.html;
```

This appears to be useless since it's always HTML. Did you forget something?

---

Your ternary needs a bit of cleaning. The way I usually do it is to line up the the `?` and `:` for visibility of the two options that come after.

```
condition1 ? foo
           : condition2 ? bar
                        : baz;
```

---

If an `if`, `for`, `while` and similar operations have blocks that have more than one line, regardless if the operation is one expression, just put `{}` for safety. Better, just use `{}` for blocks all the time.

Comment: Thanks so much for this feedback! I'll writ an example that uses the third argument. :)